# Updating generator arguments in python (networkx simple cycles)

Tags: python, generator, networkx, graph-traversal

Admittedly I am having trouble understanding some of the finer points of generators (such as the actual purpose of send()).

Here is my situation.  I am using NetworkX's simple_cycles generator to generate cycles, in search of cycles of size k.  For those who are unfamiliar, simple_cycles takes a graph as input, and does a DFS algorithm to iteratively discover cycles.

When the generator finds cycles that meet specific conditions, I sometimes want to alter my graph and start searching for cycles from the altered graph.  My question is, is it possible to alter my graph (remove edges), and pass a new graph into my old generator, resuming generation but continuing with the updated set of edges.  If I could do this, I could avoid having to traverse back over huge amounts of the graph that had already been explored.

Comment: You should create a new generator after you modify the graph. Create a generator with `nx.simple_cycles`; get the first cycle with `next`; update the graph; repeat as needed.

Comment: You won't be able to do that cleanly.  Be aware that you don't have to "pass the modified graph" into the generator.  If you modify the graph it will change the graph the generator is working with for the next call because objects are passed similarly to pointers in C.  I think Python may have tests built in that would cause the generator to exit with an error if this happens.  Even if Python allows this, I wouldn't do it.  The algorithm you're using may think some edges exist (that don't exist any more) or it may think some edges don't exist (that now exist).  So it'll give bad output.